# multiple select with count in another table

Tags: mysql, count

I have 3 Mysql tables :
Products(id, name)
Usage(id, product_id)
Usage_history(id, usage_id, status_id).

status_id can have values from 1 to 5 (given from application).

I want to search and find all products that have been used with status_id=1, more than 1 times.

Comment: there is no link beween your usage_history table which contains status_id and other tables...

Comment: There is, usage_history.usage_id <-> usage.id

Comment: Assuming a unused product doesn't have a usage record, you should be able to use inner joins.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the problem is that I cannot manage to write the SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `join` and finally filter out data with `conditional aggregation` with `group by`

```
select
p.* from products p
join `usage` u on u.product_id = p.id
join usage_history uh on uh.usage_id = u.id
group by p.id
having sum(uh.status_id = 1) > 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52690/1

Answer (score 0):

try below query-

```
SELECT pr.id,pr.name,COUNT(uh.id) AS cnt
FROM usage_history uh 
JOIN `usage` us ON us.id=uh.usage_id 
JOIN products pr ON pr.id=us.product_id 
WHERE uh.status_id=1 
GROUP BY pr.id 
HAVING cnt>1;
```